# Play audio/sound in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

May I ask about how to play the audio from Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin.Forms Portable?

As I known got Dependency Service , I saw a few sample that only got iOS and Android but does not had Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 and UWP.

Comment: There is no built in facility for this.  You need to implement it in each platform and use DI to inject into Forms.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin (which I have never used) does support Mac, Android, iOS, and UWP but does not look like it currently supports WP 8.1 or Windows 8.1. You may be able to look through the code and get a better idea about how you could accomplish it on your own though for those platforms.

https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager